# ionic 2 too much white space in ion-list

Tags: css, ionic2

i am trying to create a ion-card with some text separated by a line and then a read-only form data below it. the screenshot shows only the form data part.

i used the code like

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label><p>Close Date</p></ion-label>
        <ion-label><p>In 22 Days</p></ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label><p>Last Activity</p></ion-label>
        <ion-label><p>In 22 Days</p></ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

but this leaves too much of whitespace between the two rows. [image]

this one is the desired one.
the page looks like
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihxh3bckziyfcdp/Screenshot%202017-06-21%2012.40.27.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure which part of the attached screenshot that you're wanting to be closer, but since Ionic is just HTML/JS/CSS, you should be able to add an ID or a Class to the `<p>`'s in question and reduce their top margin.

In Ionic 3, there should be a `component.scss` file with the template `.html` file and the `.ts` file.

You can add something like this to reduce top margin:

```
page-foo {
  .tight-paragraph {
    margin-top: 2px;
  }
}
```

The selector `page-foo` should be established in your component declaration in the `.ts` file.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-foo',
  templateUrl: 'foo.html' 
})
export class FooPage {
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<ion-item-group></ion-item-group>` outside ion-item.

And you can use CSS to control the distance between the rows in the `.scss` of the same page, if it's a specific case.

Comment: i wrapped my ion-items under a single ion-item-group but i dont see distance between the rows going away

Comment: @vik  So try to use css! margin-bottom: -2px; in a class for example,and put this class in the <ion-item> tag.

Comment: what i see is a input-wrapper class is adding this extra margin somehow

Comment: try create a class .input-wrapper on the .scss of the page with margin: 0 !important;